# Character skeleton rigging not rendered, only shapekeys and object transformations are rendered

Tags: animation

All of my skeleton rigging does not get rendered. The only things that are being rendered are the shapekey animations and object transformations. At first I thought the problem might be that I might have forgotten to add key frames to the skeleton, but it seems like I have. I wonder if this has anything to do with ActionSheets?

the file [image]

Please let me know if anyone has any idea!

Comment: And is your armature modifier enabled in renders?  Look, don't make us play twenty questions here, just upload the file.

Comment: If you mean Actions created in the Non Linear Animation (NLA) Editor, it might.  You need to assign the action using a driver, and then animate the property the driver has bee assigned to.  In any case, please add your file to your question (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Got it, this is the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=K9VE3a0Q" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/K9VE3a0Q/)

Comment: There are 2 animated characters in that file.  When I render, both animations show.  (There are also some unanimated characters in that file, unanimated in viewport, that don't appear in the render whatsoever-- this looks by design.)  Which exact object do you feel is being animated in the viewport but not in the render?

Comment: @Nathan the monkey is not being rendered properly! For me when I render the monkey he is just frozen at one spot (whichever frame my pointer is pointing at)

Comment: @IveryChen Either there is something wrong with your particular computer, or there is some more fudamental misunderstanding.  Armature deformation of Monkey_Body_glow.002 is getting rendered for me.  The only changes made to your file to render were to set dimensions to 25% and set the output directory, followed by ctrl f12 to render animation.

Comment: I think it might be my computer, or if some setting on my Blender is wrong...how and where do you set the output directory?